# Solaris SunOS 5.11 Hex Editor

Tags: unix, hex-viewer

Can anyone point me at a decent hex viewer for Solaris? Looking for something with a front-end similar to bless on Ubuntu or Binary Viewer on Windows or ..almost the Delta Hex Editor Netbeans plugin.

This means:

1. Dual highlight of character vs. hex data. (my cursor shows me where I am in both windows)
2. Conversion of data under cursor to various int/float types with little/big endian toggle.
3. Ability to edit data a bonus.

The Netbeans plugin is problematic because Netbeans is slow to start, and it doesn't satisfy criteria #1. So I'm mostly using bvi at the moment. X-Windows or console is fine.

Comment: Which CPU architecture do you run Solaris on?

Comment: sparc v9 (I think this is called an UltraSparc, and I'm sure at one point it was faster than my phone)--edit: I shouldn't talk smack.  I actually think something's wrong with our particular machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As author of Delta Hex Editor plugin (nice to hear someone is actually using it), I would like to note, that there is also standalone Java/Swing application available on [deltahex.exbin.org](http://deltahex.exbin.org). Should start a little bit faster than whole IDE + plugin.

Side panel with various values is currently available only in development version thou. And only bits are editable for now...

And as to criteria #1, cursor is visible in both sections. Maybe it is hard to spot? I could fix that if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Solaris 5.11 comes with GNOME 2. Check if it has [GHex](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Ghex) in its package repository (no idea what that looks like on Solaris). If not, you should be able to install the development files for GTK+, grab the sources for an older version of GHex (like [2.24](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/ghex/2.24/)) and build them manually.

Comment: No ghex, and old GTK, but it didn't even occur to me to grab old code. That should work. And looks to be the only option

Comment: Well, 12 working hours later and I've given up on compiling the old version of GHex.  Perl's XML::Parser is required for the install, and down the rabbit hole I went.  Long story short, the packaged version of Perl is "troubled", and does not know how to use the C compiler on this machine (gcc), which CPAN (some Perl tool I now know way too much about) requires to build XML::Parser.  Dear lord.